# How to increment a variable count for nested for loop and print it

Tags: angular, angular5

In Angular 4 i am trying to create a nested for loop

```
   <div *ngFor="let p of prop">

    <div *ngFor="let a of p.values">

    Count is  {{count=count+1}}
```

How to create a local  variable count inside template and increment it every time whenever inner loop execute. I need to reuse this count at later part to fetch a data i.e. Values[count]. Name....

Output:

Count is  0
Count is  1
Count is  2
Count is  3
Count is  4

Comment: Can you not use `indexOf`? Count is `{{p.values.indexOf(a)}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the index value directly,

```
  <div *ngFor="let a of values; let i= index;">
     <h1>Count is  : {{i}} </h1>
  </div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5f8zcg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

**EDIT**

**[Updated demo for nested ngFor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5f8zcg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

**`EDIT`**

When you have values with different length in your objects, you need some sort of logic to do the calculation. I have implemented a custom pipe to do that.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'counterPipe'
})
export class CounterPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  transform(value: any): Counter {
    if (!counters.has(value)) {
      counters.set(value, new Counter());
    }
    return counters.get(value);
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5f8zcg?file=app%2Fcounter.pipe.ts)**

Comment: I have nested for loop....index will reset to zero at second set of iteration for the inner loop

Comment: nope it will not reset to zero until you redefine it, user different variable for the inner loop

Comment: I have edited my question.. Ut didn't come up correctly at firsr

Comment: If we are assigning let k=index in inside for loop it will be reset to zero at secind iteration

Comment: you want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5f8zcg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes but it won't work if length varies like below
prop = [{name:'test', values:[1,2,3,4,5]},{name:'test2', values:[5,6,7]}];
I need something that work for above input

Comment: dude! its like spoonfeeding , anyway the concept is same. let me fix this for you

Comment: it would be helpful if u could do as i have wasted lot of time going behind it

Comment: Look at the modified demo above

Comment: the demo links are no longer working :(

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as you cause i need to counter my rows in table then i come up with this solution and it works like charm for me

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i= index;"> {{ [i+1] }} </td>
```

It is simple and no need for pipes as well.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your list is someting like this

```
prop =[ {values:{}},{values:{}},{values:{}},{values:{}} ]
```

You need to add a property in values object something like SeqNo to store Sequence value

```html
<div *ngFor="let p of prop">

    <div *ngFor="let a of p.values">

        <span>Count is  {{GetSeqNo(i,j,a,prop)}} </span>

    </div>

</div>
```

```js
GetSeqNo(i, j, a, lst) {
    let Counter = 0;

    for (let k = 0; k <= i - 1; k++) {
        Counter = Counter + lst[k].values.length;
    }

    a.SeqNo = Counter + j + 1;

    return a.SeqNo;
}
```

Later you can get the count by using for loop prop[i].values[j].SeqNo